# Linking to a Trello card without the link text being replaced

Tags: trello

In the description of a Trello card I would like to link to another card, but I want the link text to be custom.

However Trello seems to unconditionally replace whatever I wrote with the title of the card. [Here's an example](https://trello.com/c/5p0W8ARh/2-this-is-a-card-whose-description-links-to-the-other-card).

The Markdown source of the card's description is

> `You should check out [this other card I made](https://trello.com/c/MxFdDPZE/1-this-is-a-card-with-a-title), it's pretty good.`

but Trello renders it like this:

[image: screenshot of the custom link text being ignored and replaced with the card's title]

Is there a way to force Trello to respect my custom link text without resorting to hacks like using a URL shortener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is to take out the "http://" and it should work how you want it to.

`[text](trello.com/c/MxFdDPZE/1-this-is-a-card-with-a-title)`

Comment: Wow, that's amazing. [Works perfectly](https://trello.com/c/BOAKCd0b/3-this-is-almost-the-same-card-but-without-https).

Comment: One disadvantage to keep in mind is that this adds `http://` back to the link, not `https://`, so this incurs an extra redirect (and is less secure, I guess). But other than that, it does the trick.

Comment: True, and it's likely to get deprecated/fixed in a future update to Trello. YMMV!

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this behavior [is intentional](https://twitter.com/trello/status/641221584187846656):

> @balpha What you're seeing is expected—we 'trellify' any Trello links, even in Markdown. We'll pass your use case on to the team, though!

and thus the answer is currently "no".

Answer (score 0):

You can used shortened links, like from [bit.ly](http://bit.ly), to get the behavior you desire. Of course, you risk your link looking suspicious but at least you get your link text.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that in my question, but of course I'd like to not have to do that.

Comment: @balpha oops! Missed that on my tiny phone screen..